# R Programming Error in cov.wt(z) : 'x' must contain finite values only

Tags: r, date

I have looked for such a long time, and haven't been able to figure out how to run Principal Component Analysis in R with the csv file I have. I continue to get this error:

`Error in cov.wt(z) : 'x' must contain finite values only`

all I have so far is

```
data <- read.csv("2014 07 24 Pct Chg Variables.csv")
pca <- princomp(data3, cor=T)

Error in cov.wt(z) : 'x' must contain finite values only
```

I have some `""` in my csv file, and have tried

```
data2 <- apply(data, 1, f1)
data3 <- as.numeric(data2)
```

where `f1` is a function to apply the mean where the value is a blank.

Answer (score 19):

`princomp.default` cannot deal with `NA` values:

```
USArrests[3,2] <- NA

princomp(USArrests, cor = TRUE)
#Error in cov.wt(z) : 'x' must contain finite values only
```

You need to handle `NA`s:

```
princomp(na.omit(USArrests), cor = TRUE)
#works
```

Or use `princomp.formula`:

```
princomp(~ ., data = USArrests, cor = TRUE)
#works too (by calling na.omit` per default)
```

Answer (score 6):

The first column was date.. once I tried

```
pca <- princomp(data[2:21], cor=T)
```

it worked.

Comment: So it was an error in the PCA function not recognizing the date format?  And removing the columns of dates led or proper operation of the PCA function?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you only send the numeric part of the matrix.

```
data=read.csv("file.csv", sep="[if not sep by comma]", header=TRUE)      
#Calculate number of rows and col
rows<-length(data[,1])
cols<-length(data[1,])
#Remove header and save each column to a matrix
for ( i in 1:rows){
   for ( j in 1:cols){
       if(data[i,j]=="NA"){
         data[i,j]="0"
       }
   }
}
pca_a=princomp(data, cor=True, covmat=NULL, scores=TRUE)
#Print scree plot
require(graphics)
plot(pca_a)
#plot pca
biplot(pca_a)
#plot scores with labels
plot(pca_a$loadings[,1:2],type="n", main="Title", sub="A subtitle")
text(pca_a$loadings[,1],pca_a$loadings[,2],c("Var1","Var2","..."))
```

That should help. This way you can change all NA or other things to 0. 
You could also remove rows that have Strings if there aren't many.